# com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input in Spring Boot App

Tags: java, spring, error-handling, jackson, jackson-databind

**SUMMARY:** I send a request from my server application to another endpoint. I get Http 401 error response. When I try to map this error body to my error class, I get an exception like:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map
>   due to end-of-input

**DETAILS:** I develop a server application with Spring Boot and jackson-datatype-jsr310. I use RestTemplate of Spring framework while sending request to another server application like:

```
public abstract class AbstractBackendAdapter {

@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper mapper;

private <T> T exchange(final String url, final HttpMethod method, final HttpEntity request,
    final Class<T> responseType) {

...

final ResponseEntity<T> response;

try {
    response = restTemplate.exchange(url, method, request, responseType);
} catch (HttpServerErrorException exception) {
    throw new BackendHttpServerException(exception, method, url, request.getHeaders());
} catch (HttpClientErrorException exception) {
    throw new BackendHttpClientException(exception, method, url, request.getHeaders());
} catch (HttpMessageNotReadableException exception) {
    throw new BackendHttpMessageNotReadableException(exception, method, url, request.getHeaders());
}
...
}
```

I don't use default Spring error handling. Instead of it, I write my exception handler class like:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

@Autowired
private ObjectMapper mapper;

@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
@ExceptionHandler(value = {BackendHttpClientException.class})
@ResponseBody
protected ErrorResponse handleBackendClientException(final BackendHttpClientException exception,
    final HttpServletResponse response) {

...

    if (HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST == httpStatus) {
        ...
    } else if (HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED == httpStatus) {
        final ClientErrorInfo error;

        try {
            error = mapper.readValue(exception.getResponseBodyAsString(), ClientErrorInfo.class);

            final String errorCode = error.getErrorCode();

            logBackendError(httpMethod, url, headers,
                httpStatus, errorCode, error.getErrorMessage(), error.getErrorCause());

            errorResponse = errorResponseConverter.prepareErrorResponse(errorCode, response);
        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            errorResponse = generateUnexpectedJsonFormatError(ioException);
        }

    }

    return errorResponse;
}
```

However, in some cases, I get Http 401 response with empty body. I mean, exception.getResponseBodyAsString() returns null. Because of that reason,  mapper.readValue(exception.getResponseBodyAsString(), ClientErrorInfo.class) cannot parse null value to ClientErrorInfo.class. Then, JsonMappingExcepiton is thrown at the line - mapper.readValue(exception.getResponseBodyAsString(), ClientErrorInfo.class). Related log is something like:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: ; line: 1, column: 0]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException.from(JsonMappingException.java:270)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._initForReading(ObjectMapper.java:3854)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:3799)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:2858)
    at com.commencis.butterfly.core.RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler.handleBackendClientException(RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler.java:145)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.doResolveHandlerMethodException(ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver.java:384)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.doResolveException(AbstractHandlerMethodExceptionResolver.java:59)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.resolveException(AbstractHandlerExceptionResolver.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.resolveException(HandlerExceptionResolverComposite.java:74)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processHandlerException(DispatcherServlet.java:1222)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1034)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:984)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.SessionRepositoryFilter.doFilterInternal(SessionRepositoryFilter.java:167)
    at org.springframework.session.web.http.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

On the other hand, when I send the same request to the same endpoint via Postman, I get Http 401 error with filled body:

```
{
    "errorCode": "ERR_C13",
    "errorMessage": "Authorization failed",
    "errorCause": "RETRIEVABLE_PNR_SR_CODE"
}
```

**EDIT-1:** By using Charles, I intervened between my server app and the endpoint that I send a request to and checked the response before my server app received. Response was something like:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=C157382C48E***9972A77DADC; Path=/crane-ticketing; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: rememberMe=deleteMe; Path=/crane-ticketing; Max-Age=0; Expires=Tue, 04-Dec-2018 13:38:02 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 100
Date: Wed, 05 Dec 2018 13:38:01 GMT
Connection: Keep-alive

{"errorCode":"ERR_C13","errorMessage":"Authorization failed","errorCause":"RETRIEVABLE_PNR_SR_CODE"}
```

**EDIT-2:** Some spring-jackson configuration lines in the application.properties like:

```
spring.jackson.serialization.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS = false
spring.jackson.serialization.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS = false
spring.jackson.deserialization.ADJUST_DATES_TO_CONTEXT_TIME_ZONE = false
spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=NON_ABSENT
spring.jackson.mapper.AUTO_DETECT_GETTERS=false
```

***How can I see the same error response with filled body in my server application with the error response in Postman? Any ideas will be appreciated!***

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add a necessary header to the request like `Content-Type: application/json`?

Comment: @aBnormaLz By using Charles, I intervened between my server app and the endpoint that I send a request to and checked the response before my server app received. You can find details of the response in the question. Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 is written there. The problem should be something different..

Answer (score 1):

After I made some debugging, I realized that the cause of the problem is code in SimpleClientHttpResponse that is a default response class of Resttemplate. Also, I found that there are some issues about this problem in Spring JIRA:

Reference: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9367

*"It is very difficult (impossible) to handle a 401 response in the RestTemplate with default settings. In fact it is possible, but you have to supply an error handler and a request factory. The error handler was obvious, but the problem is that the default request factory uses java.net which can throw HttpRetryException when you try to look at the status code of the response (despite it being obviously available). The solution is to use HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory."*

When I added the dependency written below in my POM file, my application started to handle the body of 401 response.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
</dependency>
```